# SQL вернуть целое число в запросе

Tags: mysql, sql

Возможно ли в запросе сразу вернуть целое число без точки

```
SELECT SUMM FROM USERS WHERE USER = 1
```

Возвращает `5.00` а мне нужно что запрос вернул сразу результат `5`

Answer (score 2):

По стандарту SQL преобразование типов осуществляется функцией `CAST`

```
SELECT CAST(SUMM AS INTEGER) AS SUMM FROM USERS WHERE USER = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться функцией **[ROUND](https://oracleplsql.ru/mysql-function-round.html)** для округления числа

```
SELECT ROUND(SUMM) FROM USERS WHERE USER = 1
```

Comment: Ошибка Function unknown.ROUND.

Comment: Значит это не mysql)

Comment: Извиняюсь, это запрос к  INTERBASE

Comment: Официальная документация https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round говорит, что тип результата соответствует типу аргумента. Как было дробное, так и останется.

Comment: @Федотов, измените тэги в вопросе, раз это не MySQL

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Nope. всё там нормально делается. Почитайте внимательно. Так же можете попробовать это в https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, читаю внимательно: "The return value has the same type as the first argument". А «это» не отображает тип возвращаемого значения.